# SOLR can do searching on Broker DB data only

Tags: solr, tridion, tridion-2011

We have around 100 product pages in our website which will be growing in the future. These will be having same look and feel.

I want to do search on products. I need to understand as would i need to publish product content to broker DB so that it can be indexed and queried in SOLR.
Is it correct or can we do searching on product pages published to content delivery server as well.

Cheers
Rajiv

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the Tridion site too: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://si4t.github.io/ http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/search-products-and-sdl-tridion-2011 http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/integrating-search-engines-with-sdl-tridion-2011/ http://prezi.com/kznausrbt5ta/search-integration-for-tridion/